# is "a piece of comment" appropriate and clear expression?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

assume we posted a blog just now, there is no comment yet.

after a while personA added some comment on this post.

and personB adds some comment on this post.

is it a appropriate and clear expression by saying there are "2 pieces of comment" on this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would not say, "two pieces of comment." That is not idiomatic. It should be just "two comments".

> There are two comments on this post.

If you really wanted to use "pieces of", you could say:

> There are two pieces of commentary on this post.

but that is unnecessarily wordy and would not be an improvement.